# How large must $A$ be if $\{1, \ldots, N\} \subseteq A-A$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Given a positive integer $N$, what is the size of the smallest set of integers $A$ such that, for any integer  $1 \leq k \leq N$, we can find two integers $x, y \in A$ such that $x - y = k$?  (An alternative way to write this condition is to ask that $\{1, \ldots, N\} \subseteq A-A$.)  For example, for $N=9$, we could take $A=\{-3, -2, -1, 0, 3, 6\}$, which achieves $|A|=6$.

It easy to see that $|A| \geq \sqrt{2N}$, as at most $\binom {|A|} 2 \leq |A|^2/2$ differences can be formed from the elements of $A$.  I can also construct suitable sets $A$ with $|A| = 2 \sqrt N$.

> Is the lower bound $\sqrt{2N}$ asymptotically correct? If not, what is the correct lower bound?

Comment: Try Golomb rulers.

Comment: What does the phrase *naively prove* mean? Does it mean *prove*?

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger No perfect Golomb ruler of length larger than $6$ exists, though. So, essentially $\{0,1\}$, $\{0,1,3\}$, and $\{0,1,4,6\}$ are the only ones that meet the bound $\binom{\vert A\vert}{2} \geq N$ with equality. Completeness is required for OP's purpose.

Comment: Suppose $N = k^2 - 1$. Consider $A = \{1 , \ldots , k\} \cup \{2k , 3k , \ldots , (k-1)k , k^2\}$. Then $A-A$ contains $\{1, \ldots , N\}$ and $|A| \sim 2 \sqrt{N}$. With sumset replacing difference set, see "a new upper bound for finite additive bases" by Gunturk and Nathanson.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger, There are two major difference between this problem and Golomb rulers. First, we allow negative numbers in A. Second, we allow duplicates (e.g. two pairs x, y \in A, can generate the same value).

Comment: Allowing negative numbers is unimportant because you can translate $A$.

Comment: @Douglas Zare: It is important that $A$ needn't be contained in an interval of length $N$.

Comment: Why the votes to close??

Comment: @QinJianbin, yes, but the problems are related and a literature search on one should help with the other.

Comment: In fact, the comment was also intended as a response to Seva, who remarked about an unsuccessful search.

Answer (score 10):

These are not Golomb rulers, but *difference bases*. The contrast is that Golomb rulers are a *packing problem* (differences must be *distinct*, but can be as sparse as you like), and difference bases are a *covering problem* (differences must *cover* an interval, but can overlap as much as you like).

Difference bases have been studied at least from 1948, and it seems most of the research is in asymptotic bounds.  In fact the list of known concrete values is conspicuously short: OEIS [A239308](http://oeis.org/A239308) lists values up to $a(37)=10$, indicating a basis of $10$ elements whose differences cover $[1,37]$. For $N=9$ one can take $A=\{0, 1, 4, 7, 9\}$, achieving $|A|=5$.

The current question asks about lower bounds on $|A|$ with respect to $\sqrt{N}$.

**Answer:** The proposed bound $\sqrt{2N}$ is not tight. I think the first nontrivial lower bound was $(1.5570\ldots)\sqrt{N}$ by Rédei and Rényi in 1948 (cited by Erdős and Gál; I haven't seen the original). Leech (1956) improved it to $(1.5602\ldots)\sqrt{N}$. Recently Bernshteyn and Tait (2019) showed that Leech's bound could be improved further (at least "by $\epsilon$") but they did not explicitly show how much.

Further note: A similar MO question is [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261920/what-is-the-smallest-cardinality-of-a-set-a-whose-difference-a-a-contains-n-co?rq=1). In that question, it is required that the differences cover $N$ *consecutive integers* (not necessarily $[1,N]$). But note that if $[1,N]$ is covered by $A-A$, then in fact $2N+1$ consecutive integers $[-N,N]$ are covered, so the problems are very closely linked. (See also Fedor Petrov's comment there.)

### Bibliography

*Erdős, Pál; Gál, S. A.*, On the representation of $1,2,\ldots,N$ by differences, Proc. Akad. Wet. Amsterdam 51, 1155-1158 (1948). [ZBL0032.01302](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0032.01302).

*Leech, John*, [**On the representation of $1, 2,\ldots, n$ by differences**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s1-31.2.160), J. Lond. Math. Soc. 31, 160-169 (1956). [ZBL0072.03401](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0072.03401).

*Bernshteyn, Anton; Tait, Michael*, [**Improved lower bound for difference bases**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2019.05.002), J. Number Theory 205, 50-58 (2019). [ZBL07101901](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:07101901).